# Запятые при неполных придаточных

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, тире

Помогите, пожалуйста, в следующем вопросе. Есть два предложения:

**Чему учить(,) хорошо говаривал Д. И. Менделеев.**

**Как учить(,) подсказывает многолетний, но невнедренный опыт МФТИ (Физтеха).**

Хотелось бы уточнить: здесь **чему учить** и **как учить** — это ведь неполные предложения, и запятая, соответственно, нужна? Вряд ли их можно назвать цельными по смыслу выражениями типа *есть чем заняться* и *было о чем подумать*...

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю смысл сказанного, здесь уместно тире:

Чему учить – (об этом) хорошо говаривал Д. И. Менделеев.
Как учить – (это) подсказывает многолетний, но не внедренный опыт МФТИ (Физтеха).

Примечание. Правило гласит, что *не* с причастием пишется раздельно, если есть противопоставление. (См. [§70. Правописание не с причастиями](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#%D0%B7_08)). У Вас: многолетний, но не внедренный.

Comment: Разве _многолетний_ противопоставляется _невнедренному_? За тире - спасибо большое! Действительно, оно уместнее...

Comment: Думаю, противопоставление внедренному здесь все-таки подразумевается, а этого достаточно, чтобы писать раздельно.

Comment: С тире согласна, а насчёт слитного написания - как автор написал, так и верно, ведь наличие предполагаемого противопоставления может подтвердить только автор, я вот его не вижу, по-моему, прямо по правилу:Пишется слитно не с полными причастиями, при которых нет пояснительных слов, например: невычитанная рукопись, незамеченные опечатки, непроверенные цитаты, н т.д. Невнедрённый=теоретический

Answer (score 2):

По поводу тире верно, **это бессоюзные предложения с придаточным изъяснительным в препозиции.**

[Розенталь. § 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)

Тире ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует:
1) придаточная изъяснительная: Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять (Г.)

По поводу  раздельного написания НЕ я не уверена (нужна ссылка) , но можно изменить предложение: Как учить — подсказывает многолетний, но так и  не внедренный опыт МФТИ.

Comment: 4.   Пишется раздельно не с причастиями, при которых имеется или предполагается противопоставление, например: не законченный, а только начатый рассказ. (http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm#з_08)

Comment: Это не противопоставление, а уступительная конструкция с НО. Помните, что такое уступка? Мы ожидаем, что многолетний опыт должен быть внедрен, а он по каким-то причинам таковым не является. Потенциальная причина не имеет ожидаемого следствия.

Comment: Согласен, это уступительная конструкция. Однако, мне кажется, все равно противопоставление подразумевается, а этого достаточно, чтобы писать раздельно. Ну, как минимум, оба варианта возможны.